# Local images are not loading In Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a new `vue` site which was built using `vue-cli` but my image will not load at all and can't figure out why

```
 <router-link class="logo" to="/" tag="img" src="@/assets/logo.png" style="cursor: pointer"/>
```

I have the `image` saved in the `assets` folder

[image]

[image]

console

[image]

[image]

But if I use the below it does display

```
<img src="@/assets/logo.png" />
```

[image]

console

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With vue cli images are considered as modules so you should import or require them  :

```
 <router-link :src="require(@/assets/logo.png)" style="cursor: pointer" class="logo" to="/" tag="img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, `<router-link>` does not have a `src` prop: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props

Comment: The `router-link` is rendered as an `HTML` `img` so the `src` is valid

Comment: according to [this](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#tag) : ***Sometimes we want <router-link> to render as another tag, e.g <li>. Then we can use tag prop to specify which tag to render to, and it will still listen to click events for navigation***

Comment: It matters that `router-link` doesn't have a `src` prop: since it doesn't itself know about the `src` prop it's going to pass the value as-is. It's not like Vue looks at all attributes everywhere to see if they look like paths that should be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Vue with Webpack (almost always), [Vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org) is used to compile your `.vue` files. When compiling `<template>` part of the file, it looks for some common tags like `<img>` and is able to [transform](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html) content of the `src` tags into Webpack module requests

So your `<img src="@/assets/logo.png" />` is at compile time transformed (essentially) into `<img :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')" />`

See the link above for tag/attribute combinations transformed by default. If the combination you need is not there (as in your case), you can either configure Vue-loader ([transformAssetUrls](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls)) as many popular UI libraries do (for example Vuetify for it's `v-img` component) or you must do it by hand as @Boussadjra Brahim suggested (with missing quotes tho):

```html
<router-link :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')" to="/" tag="img" />
```